# Excel formula: picking a value from a table/array of non-unique values

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

OK, so here's the problem that's got me stumped in Excel. I have three columns:

```
date    value   fruit
5-Jan   19  apple
5-Jan   2   banana
6-Jan   8   grapefruit
6-Jan   2   lemon
6-Jan   14  orange
5-Jan   8   peach
1-Jan   14  pear
6-Jan   4   starfruit
10-Jan  3   strawberry
```

The data is not sorted in any way. The dates, values, and fruits are non-unique.

I'm going to copy and paste the date values into the first column of another table, and remove duplicates.  I need a formula to paste into the second column of that table that will, for each date, identify the fruit with the highest value.

Here's the expected outcome from that formula.

```
date    fruit
1-Jan   pear
5-Jan   apple
6-Jan   orange
10-Jan  strawberry
```

I've been playing around with index/match, vlookup, arrays (which baffle me), and I'm stumped.

Ideas?  Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With `EXCEL-365` try below

```
=@INDEX(SORT(FILTER($B$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10=F2),1,-1),,2)
```

For older version of excel try below array formula-

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$10,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$10=F2,IF($B$2:$B$10=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$10=F2,$B$2:$B$10,"")),ROW($B$2:$B$10)-ROW($B$1),""),""),1))
```

Array formula needs CSE entry means press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe sort and unique would work in Excel 365 as well.